# How to compare two text files and high light the difference using java?

Tags: java

I have two text file with some content, i need to compare two file line by line and high light the difference like any version control system (svn, cvs etc.). Could any one can help me here?

Comment: show something what you tried?

Comment: I'm sure there are lots who *could* help you, it just depends on the *boundary conditions*.

Comment: public static void compareFiles(InputStream is1, InputStream is2) throws IOException {
     Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(is1);
     Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(is2);
     while (sc1.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext()) {
         String str1 = sc1.next();
         String str2 = sc2.next();
         if (!str1.equals(str2))
             System.out.println(str1 + " != " + str2);
     }
     while (sc1.hasNext())
         System.out.println(sc1.next() + " != EOF");
     while (sc2.hasNext())
         System.out.println("EOF != " + sc2.next());
     sc1.close();
     sc2.close();
 }

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar project. You can check [this link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DiffAlgorithm). This will help you conceptually. I can provide the code also but that will not help your understanding. Try to implement yourself you will enjoy. \m/